# lualatex.fmt is missing

Tags: luatex

On a fresh ubuntu texlive installation a compilation with `lualatex` gives the  error that `lualatex.fmt` can not be found:

```
> lualatex document.tex

This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt lualatex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/user/.texlive2019/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/user/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=lualatex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 0
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `lualatex.fmt'!
```

This is a minimum version of a file to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Beamer Template}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Does any one know what went wrong here or how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: mktexfmt seems to find only a local fmtutil.cnf which probably is empty. Where is the main one? Did you try fmtutil-sys --byfmt=lualatex?

Comment: Yes, I did `fmtutil-sys`, but it didn't change anything.  `fmtutil.cnf`is located at 
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf and 
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf. Does it make sense to create a sym link, or is there a more serious problem?

Comment: I don't have ubuntu and don't know why the normal fmtutil.cnf is not found. I will have to wait for someone with this OS.

Comment: I just tried it on a 18.04 Ubuntu, there everything still works. The error occurs only on a 20.04 Ubuntu. If anyone can confirm that  I will file a bug report. Otherwise, any ideas or fixes are of course welcome!

Comment: Fails for me on 18.04 ubuntu. I just updated from texlive 2020 to 2021